# Chapter 2 question 17 (a) Calculus by Spivak

Tags: calculus, analysis

I am having trouble understanding the solution to this problem. The question wants us to prove that if a natural number>1 is not prime, then it can be written as the product of primes.

It says to solve it using complete induction.

The answer says; Suppose that every number < n can be written as a product of primes. If n>1 is not a prime, then n = ab for a, b < n. By assumption, a and b are each products of primes so n = ab is also.

My question is: The book says to prove with complete induction you must first prove for p(1) but I don't see where it has been proven for this base case in the answer provided (in fact I don't see how you could prove it for 1 because it is not prime and can not be written as a product of primes).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The empty product is $1$ by definition.

Comment: @anne Bauval, thanks for the response. I was wondering exactly what you mean by "the empty product is 1 by definition"? sorry I'm still learning. I understand now that we don't have to prove for 1, but now I'm having difficulty understanding the assumption "suppose that every natural number < n can be written as a product of primes" I can't think of a base case in which this would be true. like if n = 3 for instance then 2 which is less than 3 can not be written as a factor of primes? I'm so confused.

Comment: Let $P(n)$ be the property "$n$ is a product of primes", including the empty product ($1$) and the singleton products (the primes). The base case $P(1)$ is true, and for any integer $n>1,$  if $P(k)$ holds for every $k\in\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ then etc.

Comment: @AnneBauval oh so prime numbers are also considered factors of primes. Now I get it Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use 1 as your base case. You say "if $n>1$ is not a prime, then $n = ab$ for $a,b <n$", which has the important implication that (positive) $a,b<n$ and $ab = n$ implies $a,b > 1$. So it's sufficient to use n=2 as your base case, since the relevant a,b factors will always be larger than 1.

In general, with induction, you choose your base case to match the problem.

Comment: thanks for the response, using this idea you gave me I came up with a proof that makes sense, let me know if it's correct:                                                                 Base case: P(2) is a prime so it's a product of primes.                                                                         Assume that all numbers k are products of primes for 1<k<=n                                        Then if n is not prime n = a*b for a,b<n so a,b>1 which puts a,b between 1 and n so they are product of primes

Comment: "If $n>1$ is not a prime then $n=ab$ for some $1<a\leq b<n$." $$n\text{ is not prime }:={\exists a\in\Bbb N\,\exists b\in\Bbb N\,(1<a\leq b<n)}$$

Comment: Nice explanation 